# How to track traffic and page navigation for Rails app in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku. I would like to have statistics on who are coming to my site, from where, how long they spend on each page, what are the paths they went through etc.

What are the options? Should I use app built for Heroku or use Rails gem,  and which one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think question most relevant to statistics,and analytic,
You can add Google analytic and web master tool or any other analytic tool(http://get.gaug.es/).
You can put script in layout file so it can be applicable for all pages.